# Python - how to get last line in a loop

Tags: python, csv, iteration

I have some CSV files that I have to modify which I do through a loop. The code loops through the source file, reads each line, makes some modifications and then saves the output to another CSV file. In order to check my work, I want the first line and the last line saved in another file so I can confirm that nothing was skipped.

What I've done is put all of the lines into a list then get the last one from the index minus 1. This works but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to accomplish this.

Code sample:

```
def CVS1():
  fb = open('C:\\HP\\WS\\final-cir.csv','wb')
  check = open('C:\\HP\\WS\\check-all.csv','wb')
  check_count = 0
  check_list = []
  with open('C:\\HP\\WS\\CVS1-source.csv','r') as infile:
    skip_first_line = islice(infile, 3, None)
    for line in skip_first_line:       
       check_list.append(line)
       check_count += 1
       if check_count == 1:
         check.write(line)

     [CSV modifications become a string called "newline"]

     fb.write(newline)

final_check = check_list[len(check_list)-1]
check.write(final_check)
fb.close()
```

Comment: As a side note, using random indentation not only makes your code hard to read, it also leads to `IndentationError`s or incorrect code—those last three lines are not actually part of `CVS1` as written. Also, naming a function `CVS` because it handles _CSV_ files is probably not a good idea. The compiler may not get confused, but anyone reading your code will. And does `fb` mean something? Finally, you're using a `with` statement for `infile`… why not for `fb` and `check` as well? (Did you notice that you forgot to `close()` one of those files?)

Comment: @abarnert, I'm sorry about that. I tried to paste the code in and then choose "Code" in the editor window, but it didn't work on the top half of my code. I had to manually add the 4 spaces.

Comment: @abarnet: fb was just in order progression. I named my file objects fa, fb, fc in the beginning. I need to clean up the code. Similarly with using `with` and `infile` - I learned those later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate the csv rows of inpunt file, and check the index, like this:

```
def CVS1():
    with open('C:\\HP\\WS\\final-cir.csv','wb') as  fb, open('C:\\HP\\WS\\check-all.csv','wb') as check, open('C:\\HP\\WS\\CVS1-source.csv','r') as infile:
        skip_first_line = islice(infile, 3, None)
        for idx,line in enumerate(skip_first_line):       
            if idx==0 or idx==len(skip_first_line):
            check.write(line)
            #[CSV modifications become a string called "newline"]
            fb.write(newline)
```

I've replaced the open statements with `with` block, to delegate to interpreter the files handlers

Comment: does using the cascaded `with` statements mean I have several nested loops? I try to avoid them as much as possible.

Comment: it only means that you have 3 handlers, one per block, and when it get finished the interpreter do the job with handlers. It's only more pythonic-file style

Comment: `with` statements aren't loops, and there are no performance implications to cascading them like this. However, it is a bit of a readability problem, and unless you need to support Python 2.5, there's no reason to have three nested `with` statements instead of a single statement with three contexts. (If you're wondering how to fit it on 3 lines—just store the paths in variables above the `with`, `checkpath` is a lot shorter than `'C:\\HP\\WS\\check-all.csv'`.)

Comment: thanks @abarnert i've just changed, adding your advice, to improve the answer

Answer (score 2):

If you actually need `check_list` for something, then, as the other answers suggest, using `check_list[-1]` is equivalent to but better than `check_list[len(check_list)-1]`.

But do you really need the list? If all you want to keep track of is the first and last lines, you don't. If you keep track of the first line specially, and keep track of the current line as you go along, then at the end, the first line and the current line are the ones you want.

In fact, since you appear to be writing the first line into `check` as soon as you see it, you don't need to keep track of anything but the current line. And the current line, you've already got that, it's `line`.

So, let's strip all the other stuff out:

```
def CVS1():
    fb = open('C:\\HP\\WS\\final-cir.csv','wb')
    check = open('C:\\HP\\WS\\check-all.csv','wb')
    first_line = True
    with open('C:\\HP\\WS\\CVS1-source.csv','r') as infile:
        skip_first_line = islice(infile, 3, None)
            for line in skip_first_line:       
                if first_line:
                    check.write(line)
                    first_line = False

                [CSV modifications become a string called "newline"]

                fb.write(newline)

            check.write(line)    
            fb.close()
```

Comment: I tried to do something like this in my first set of code, but the line before last `check.write(line)` didn't appear to append the last line. My original code includes a (clumsy) counter called "check_count" (I like your solution better). Let me try this again.

Comment: @Tensigh: Look at the comments on your question. If you never close `check`, you may not see the last write to it immediately (or, at least in theory, you may _never_ see it). If you have stuff at the wrong indentation level so it isn't part of the function, it won't run as part of the function. Either one of those could be causing the problem you saw.

Comment: I just tried this but it only writes the first line. The last line never appears in the file.

Comment: I thought that might be the issue, but I checked and I do have `check.close()` as the next to last line. Since I can't post the new code here, I'll modify the code block above.

Comment: I tried it again and now both lines (first and last) write to the check file, but now the target file (circle-final.csv) only has the last line. I'll post the code tomorrow.

Comment: @Tensigh: I'll give you 3:1 odds that it's another indentation problem. Looking at your original post, your `fb.write(newline)` is dedented outside of the `for` loop. If that's true in your real code, then you're only going to call it once, at the end, which would cause exactly what you're seeing. Get yourself a decent editor that indents 4 spaces, and copy and paste code between your editor and SO instead of retyping it, and these kinds of problems will go away.

Comment: you're probably right, I tried it with an earlier set of code and it worked. I'm using Notepad++ as an editor, btw. But I can't indent the first line of code, right? So the problem remains unless I insert 4 spaces on each line (which Notepad++ can do, I've just never posted more than 4 lines of code before).

Comment: Hold on, are you talking about indenting the whole code block for SO? The way you do that is to paste your properly-indented code here, select it, then click the `{}` button, and it indents everything 4 spaces; no need to try to do it manually.

Comment: Yes, that's been a problem I've had with pasting code into SO. It's properly indented in Notepad++ (as evidenced by the fact that it runs) but pasting it into SO never works unless I manually add the 4 spaces. I highlighted my pasted code and clicked the "CODE" choice in the editing window but it didn't work previously.

Comment: @Tensigh: Any chance you're using tabs instead of/in addition to spaces in your source code? Because that tends to cause problems like this one—and also problems in your code, because what your editor shows as the indentation may not be the same thing Python actually sees.

Comment: Not on my work computer, I fixed Notepad++ so that it doesn't do that (it was a problem I had in my first days of using NP++). With Python you HAVE to indent (one of its blessings and curses) so I've learned to be pretty conscientious about indenting. The code not writing all lines was a mystery because the line `fb.write(newline)` is IN the `for line in skip_first_line:` block. Either way, I think I have enough clues to figure it out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you can access the index `-1` directly:

```
final_check = check_list[-1]
```

which is nicer than what you have now:

```
final_check = check_list[len(check_list)-1]
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know I could do that.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not an empty or 1 line file you can:

```
my_file = open(root_to file, 'r')
my_lines = my_file.readlines()
first_line = my_lines[0]
last_line = my_lines[-1]
```

Comment: If I read this code directly, it's copying the lines directly from the source file. That's not a bad idea but what I wanted to do was take the first and last line from what was being edited so I can show the whole file was read as it was being edited. This would show that what I edited was the entire file since the first and last edited line match the source file.

Comment: @Tensigh my code was simply a guide for you how to get the first and last lines, you can take them and compare in your loop. when you hit the first and last lines before the edit. it may not be the fastest solution but it's very simple.